# How to put queue-in and queue-out timestamp in MQTT / Find MQTT latency

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to find the queuing time in MQTT queues such as arrival time as the event enters the queue and the ingestion time when the event is taken from the queue. Subtracting both these times can give me queueing delay. How do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no queuing in MQTT (apart for offline clients with high QOS subscriptions), messages are delivered to all clients subscribed to a topic as soon as it is received by the broker.

If you want to know how long it takes a broker to process a new message then it will depend on the  broker, the machine it's running on, the number of clients subscribed to the topic (and at what QOS) and what the load level is. You may be able to calculate this by increasing the logging on your given broker, but this will be broker specific and any increase in logging level is likely to increase the latency as well. Your best bet would be to look at the network traffic to track inbound and outbound messages, something like wireshark would probably be best.

Comment: Thanks for answering but my problem will not be completely solved by Wireshark as I want to use queue-in and queue-out times with other times like detection time for each event. For most of the times, I need to find min(queue-in) time for a certain time window. Also, I am using QoS 0, 1 and 2 interchangeably in my experiments.

Comment: As is said there is NO queuing for normal MQTT message delivery, Also for high QOS delivery you need to take the multipart confirmation into account.

Comment: I understand what you said, but the issue is that  MQTT broker is sending the streams to CEP engine which is of blocking nature which means if CEP engine is processing it will not welcome any messages from the broker. I was able to solve this problem in Android device by using a blocking queue which sends the messages to CEP engine. But now I have the problem in IoT server case in which MQTT broker gets the streaming data and sends it to CEP engine. I want to find the queuing in this case believing that broker will persist the streams unless they are consumed by CEP engine

Comment: For QOS 0 messages they will back up on the clients TCP stack, for QOS1/2 the broker will block messages until the QOS handshake is complete, but this controlled by how the broker is configure (`max_inflight_messages` on mosquitto)